# laravel select all row from 3 table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

What could I do to select all column 1 row from 3 table in laravel 5.4 ?

I want to select posts, comments , users where `post_id = comment.post_id` and `comment.user_id = user.id`.

show it in single page post with `post_title`, Comment By username

I has 3 table like this

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->text('title');
      $table->longText('description');
      $table->text('image');
      $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->longText('comment');
      $table->integer('user_id');
      $table->integer('post_id');
      $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('users',function (Blueprint $table){
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->string('username',30)->unique();
      $table->string('email')->unique();
      $table->string('password',60);
      $table->rememberToken();
      $table->timestamps();
});
```

thank for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do that using Eloquent relationships lazy loading of data.

Best place to start is to read https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
$items = \DB::table('post')
->leftJoin('comment','comment.post_id', '=', 'post.post_id')
->leftJoin('user','user.user_id', '=', 'comment.user_id')
->where('user.user_id',$user_id)
->get();
```

Comment: You can do this as well. But not recommended as it is expensive operation. Best option is to establish relationship and retrieve data using lazy loading. You can also retrieve eagerly suing with clause.